# Liferay Organization site .vs. a site which is assigned to organization

Tags: liferay

We are implementing a Liferay 6. 2 solution, everything was set but then we had a problem. Thing is, we are importing all the users from AD using LDAP with their group information. So, in liferay, we will have users and users' group. We planned to follow organization->sub-organization structure but the customer does not want to assign all the users(no option to assign user groups to organization which i know why and it totally make sense ) to the organization manually which, kind of, makes sense. So, then we had to change our design, now what we are doing is actually creating a department-wise site then assigning user groups to the site and then linking site to organization. So two questions.

1. Does it make any sense to have organization? if so then what advantages will I have in this particular case.
2. Do you see any drawbacks in our approach or should we follow a better approach which we are not aware of.